# jquery tabs - change tab after ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui-tabs

i use jquery-ui tabs component. this is code in my page

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Anagrafica</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Corsi</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Pagamenti</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="tabs-1">
    //
</div>  
<div id="tabs-2">
    //
</div>
<div id="tabs-3">
    //
</div>
```

The components works perfect

is there a way to change displayed tab after ajax call?

when i perform ajax call tab2  is showed. i want display tab3 after ajax call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, just use the `active` option:

```
$("ul").tabs("option", "active", 1); // Select tab 2
```

Answer (score 3):

Try these tabs without jQueryUI

```
$('ul').each(function(){
    var $active, $content, $links = $(this).find('a');

    //Set focus when the page is reloaded
    $active = $($links.filter('[href="'+location.hash+'"]')[0] || $links[0]);
    $active.parent().addClass('active');
    $content = $($active.attr('href'));

    //Hide containers
    $links.not($active).each(function () {
        $($(this).attr('href')).hide();
    });

    //Set click event
    $(this).on('click', 'a', function(e){
        $active.parent().removeClass('active');
        $content.hide();
        $active = $(this);
        $content = $($(this).attr('href'));
        $active.parent().addClass('active');
        $content.show();
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```